# How can i create new Component in joomla1.6?

Tags: components, joomla1.6

i am new in developer of joomla. which is the best way to develop joompla component. MVC or simple joomla Component. Anyone here help me and give me suggestion what to do? Is there any link for MVC structure joomla component creation. I will be create basic Component but i want to create component with multiple view. like category subcategory and product list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!1.7_-_Part_01#Introduction) may help you..

This is the basic hello world application which help's you to create your own component.

[This is](http://www.joomladevuser.com/tutorials/components/2-component-develompment-with-example-part-i-the-frontend) the another example which helps you at frontend